# How to convert a numpy.array to binary?

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I'm using the following function with Python2.7:

```
def array2int(pixels):
    out = 0
    for bit in pixels:
        out = (out << 1) | bit
    return out
```

Which usually works, but if I pass

```
v=np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
array2int(v.astype(int))
```

it returns `-262145`.

Comment: `out = (out << 1) | int(bit)` is a quick fix

Comment: You could also try: `int("".join(map(str, v)), 2)`

Comment: @pault doesn't work for booleans, tough ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer ahah, well in that case you can use this modification: `int("".join(map(lambda x: str(int(x)), v.astype(bool))), 2)`

Answer (score 3):

Unlike Python, numpy by default uses fixed size integers. Those can overflow:

```
1<<65
# 36893488147419103232 # correct
npone = np.ones([1], dtype=int)[0]
npone
# 1
type(npone)
# <class 'numpy.int64'>
npone<<65
# 2 # wrong
```

When adding or bitwise oring or whatever a python int and a numpy int, numpy typically wins and the result will be a numpy int:

```
out = 1
type(out)
# <class 'int'>
out = (out << 1) | npone
type(out)
# <class 'numpy.int64'>
```

To prevent that from happening in your function you can explicitly cast `bit` to a proper `int`:

```
        out = (out << 1) | int(bit)
```